# Change printer half-toning programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, settings, gdi

I'm trying to change printer default half-toning method using C#. I cannot find any information how can I achieve this and SO is the last option I think. Basically I'm writing application to change printer port settings and halftone is one of the last things I need to change.

[image]

Comment: It is only technically possible.  You'd have to call PrinterSettings.GetHdevmode(), modify the *driver specific* setting and call SetHdevmode().  Maybe this [codeproject.com project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488737/Storing-and-recalling-printer-settings-in-Csharp-n) helps, it doesn't look terribly kosher.  Using PrintDialog or Control Panel is the easy way.

Comment: As far as I know, half-toning is one of the basic (not printer private) printer driver options (build in windows printer driver) and is not possible to set it using DEVMODE. I could be wrong...